# Matching regular expression with delimited string in unix

Tags: bash

I need to match the below delimited regular expression in bash script:

```
number|my_name|number
```

I have tried the below but could not get it through end:

```
sed -e 's/[^[[digit]]*//g
```

Comment: What is your requirements?

Comment: if the above pattern (number|my_name|number) is not macthed in my file, i have to print a message exit the loop.

Comment: It's not fit with your `sed` command, can you make it more clear with example input and expected output?

Comment: i have the file with many lines like "number|my_name|number". If that format is not in my file for any of the line, i have to validate this and exit

Comment: `sed -n '/[[:digit:]]\+|my_name|[[:digit:]]\+/! {F; s//Have line don’t match/p;q}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean you are searching for patterns in a file not matching. Use `grep -v` for that.

```
grep -v "^[[:digit:]]\+|[^|]\+|[[:digit:]]\+$" <input
```

But basically you are asking about how to write regular expressions. Read `regex(7)` for that and keep in mind that each command uses other quotation rules for special characters. But most basic linux commands use the rules from `regex(7)`.